# how to reload a div with form content using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on creating an online visitor chat software using PHP and MySQL. What am i trying to do is load the page on clicking the submit button

- id for submit button: send
- id for visitor:vid
- id for chat:cid

Below is the code snippet for Ajax request made by the code but it is not working.
I have put few alerts within the codes to test whether the function is working fine or not and the function is not working.

Please help me out.
Any other method is also accepted

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#send").click(function() {
var cid = $("#cid").val();
var vid = $("#vid").val();
var usermsg = $("#usermsg").val();
var  submitmsg = $("#submitmsg").val();

var dataString = 'cid='+ cid + '&vid=' + vid + '&usermsg=' + usermsg;
alert(datastring);  
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "chat.php",
data: dataString,
success:function(result){
    alert(result);
}});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, so we need you php code here.

Comment: "but its not working fine" What is not working exactly ?

Comment: can you paste your code inside $(function(){// paste your code here})

Comment: @djidi no ajax request could be made, page is not reloaded properly wioth content trnasferred to chat.php

Comment: @Kapilgopinath nothing goes fine sir.....the problem is till the sam3e

Comment: any javacript error in the console.

Comment: Put die($_POST); at first of your chat.php file and put on ajax success console.log(result); to see is exactly ajax call is happening??

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your click function under

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // your click event here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#send").click(function() {
    var cid = $("#cid").val();
    var vid = $("#vid").val();
    var usermsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    var  submitmsg = $("#submitmsg").val();

    var dataString = 'cid='+ cid + '&vid=' + vid + '&usermsg=' + usermsg;
    alert(datastring);  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chat.php",
        data: dataString,
        success:function(result){
            alert(result);
        }});

    });
});
</script>
```